# List only bind mounts

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

Rather than using `mount | grep`, I'd like to use `mount -l -t bind`, but that doesn't work, and `-t none` shows *all* mounts.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Bind mounts are not a filesystem type, nor a parameter of a mounted filesystem; they're parameters of a mount *operation*. As far as I know, the following sequences of commands lead to essentially identical system states as far as the kernel is concerned:

```
mount /dev/foo /mnt/one; mount --bind /mnt/one /mnt/two
mount /dev/foo /mnt/two; mount --bind /mnt/two /mnt/one
```

So the only way to remember what mounts were bind mounts is the log of `mount` commands left in `/etc/mtab`. A bind mount operation is indicated by the `bind` mount *option* (which causes the filesystem type to be ignored). But `mount` has no option to list only filesystems mounted with a particular set of sets of options. Therefore you need to do your own filtering.

```
mount | grep -E '[,(]bind[,)]'
</etc/mtab awk '$4 ~ /(^|,)bind(,|$)/'
```

Note that `/etc/mtab` is only useful here if it's a text file maintained by `mount`. Some distributions set up `/etc/mtab` as a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts` instead; `/proc/mounts` is mostly equivalent to `/etc/mtab` but does have a few differences, one of which is not tracking bind mounts.

One piece of information that is retained by the kernel, but not shown in `/proc/mounts`, is when a mount point only shows a part of the directory tree on the mounted filesystem. In practice this mostly happens with bind mounts:

```
mount --bind /mnt/one/sub /mnt/partial
```

In `/proc/mounts`, the entries for `/mnt/one` and `/mnt/partial` have the same device, the same filesystem type and the same options. The information that `/mnt/partial` only shows the part of the filesystem that's rooted at `/sub` is visible in the per-process mount point information in [`/proc/$pid/mountinfo`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) (column 4). Entries there look like this:

```
12 34 56:78 / /mnt/one rw,relatime - ext3 /dev/foo rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
12 34 56:78 /sub /mnt/partial rw,relatime - ext3 /dev/foo rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Comment: @Gilles Actually, you can do this simply using `findmnt | fgrep [` as [explained here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33586/11052).

Comment: @Gilles What `mount --version` are you using that records any `bind` information in `/etc/mtab`? I am using version 2.20.1 and I looked at the latest sources and in neither case do I see bind information recorded anywhere that would allow you to grep for `bind`. On the other hand, what I suggested in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33586/11052) does in fact list bind mounts created with `--bind` as well as using the `bind` *option*.

Comment: @aculich `</etc/mtab awk …` is POSIX-compliant (I forget whether it's supported in Bourne). Please check your facts. I can confirm that `/etc/mtab` has the `bind` option for a filesystem mounted with `mount --bind /source /target` on Debian stable (mount from util-linux-ng 2.17.2).

Comment: @Gilles I deleted my errant comment to remove confusion. You're right, it is indeed POSIX-compliant. Also now I understand the reason we are seeing different behavior of `mount` and `/etc/mtab`. You are using Debian stable which has the older version of util-linux-ng; I am using Debian testing which has a newer version that no longer seems to have the same `/etc/mtab` behavior, which is maybe why @rozcietrzewiacz did not see `bind` in in `/etc/mtab` if his distribution is also using a newer version?

Comment: @aculich I see the same results on mount from util-linux 2.20.1 on Debian testing. Kernel 2.6.32 in both cases, I don't think it matters for the `/etc/mtab` content but I'm not sure.

Comment: Incidentaly, '[,(]bind[,)]' is also the monster who ate your shield in the original Legend of Zelda.

Comment: @aculich You should post `findmnt` as an answer. It only works if the target directory is not another mount point, by the way. Try for example `sudo mount --bind / foo && findmnt | grep foo`

Comment: You say that binds mounts are parameters of a "mount operation", but I don't see how that would prevent the kernel from maintaining any record of a particular mount being a bind mount. In fact, it must retain some record of it or store some flag that indicates a particular mount is a bind mount in order for it to know to connect a certain directory to another as if it were a traditional mount.

Answer (score 40):

Maybe this could do the trick:

```
findmnt | grep  "\["
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ sudo mount --bind /media/ /tmp/foo
$ findmnt | grep  "\["
│ └─/tmp/foo                     /dev/sda2[/media] ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

Comment: Apparently, this only works when a subdirectory of a mountpoint is bind mounted. If `/` itself is bind mounted, for example, the output doesn't have a `[...]`.

Comment: findmnt uses `/proc/self/mountinfo` so you can check there directly as well.

Comment: careful with this command. There will be false positives if subvolumes from btrfs are mounted. So be aware. Still a good and valid way to find bind mounts.

Answer (score 20):

The kernel doesn't handle bind mounts different from *normal* mounts after the fact. The only differ in what happens while `mount` runs.

When you mount a filesystem (eg. with `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt`) the kernel (a bit simplified) performs three steps:

1. The kernel looks for a filesystem driver for the specified filesystem type (if you omit `-t` or use `-t auto` `mount` guesses the type for you and provides the guessed type to the kernel)
2. The kernel instructs the filesystem driver to access the filesystem using the source path and any provided options. At this point the filesystem is only identified by a major:minor number pair.
3. The filesystem is bound to a path (the mountpoint). The kernel also uses some of the mount options here. (`nodev` for example is an option on the mountpoint, not on the filesystem. You can have a bind mount with `nodev` and one without)

If you perform a bind mount (eg. with `mount --bind /a /b`) the following happens:

1. The kernel resolves which filesystem contains the source path and the relative path from the mountpoint to the directory.
2. The filesystem is bound to the new mountpoint using the options and the relative path.

(I'll skip `mount --move`, because it's not relevant to the question.)

**This quite is similar to how files are created on Linux:**

1. The kernel resolves which filesystem is responsible for the directory in which the file should be created.
2. A new file in the filesystem is created. At this point the file only has an inode number.
3. The new file is linked to a filename in the directory.

If you make a hard link the following happens:

1. The kernel resolves the inode number of the source file.
2. The file is linked to the destination filename.

As you can see, the created file and the hard link are indistinguishable:

```
$ touch first
$ ln first second
$ ls -li
1184243 -rw-rw-r-- 2 cg909 cg909 0 Feb 20 23:56 /tmp/first
1184243 -rw-rw-r-- 2 cg909 cg909 0 Feb 20 23:56 /tmp/second
```

**But**, as you can identify all hardlinks to a file by comparing the inode numbers, you can identify all mounts to a filesystem by comparing the major:minor numbers of mounts.

You can do this with `findmnt -o TARGET,MAJ:MIN` or by directly looking at `/proc/self/mountinfo` ([see the Linux kernel documentation for more information](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)).

The following Python script lists all bind mounts. It assumes that the oldest mount point with the shortest relative path to the root of the mounted file system is the original mount.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os.path, re
from collections import namedtuple

MountInfo = namedtuple('MountInfo', ['mountid', 'parentid', 'devid', 'root', 'mountpoint', 'mountoptions', 'extra', 'fstype', 'source', 'fsoptions'])

mounts = {}

def unescape(string):
    return re.sub(r'\\([0-7]{3})', (lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 8))), string)

with open('/proc/self/mountinfo', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Parse line
        mid, pid, devid, root, mp, mopt, *tail = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        extra = []
        for item in tail:
            if item != '-':
                extra.append(item)
            else:
                break
        fstype, src, fsopt = tail[len(extra)+1:]
        # Save mount info
        mount = MountInfo(int(mid), int(pid), devid, unescape(root), unescape(mp), mopt, extra, fstype, unescape(src), fsopt)
        mounts.setdefault(devid, []).append(mount)

for devid, mnts in mounts.items():
    # Skip single mounts
    if len(mnts) <= 1:
        continue
    # Sort list to get the first mount of the device's root dir (if still mounted)
    mnts.sort(key=lambda x: x.root)
    src, *binds = mnts
    # Print bind mounts
    for bindmount in binds:
        if src.root == bindmount.root:
            srcstring = src.mountpoint
        else:
            srcstring = src.mountpoint+':/'+os.path.relpath(bindmount.root, src.root)
        print('{0} -> {1.mountpoint} ({1.mountoptions})'.format(srcstring, bindmount))
```

Comment: the best practical answer! identification by major:minor is very cool

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the other findmnt answer, but avoids the formatting issue.

To show all submounts:

```
findmnt --kernel -n --list | grep '\['
```

To show all submounts of filesystems of type ext4:

```
findmnt --kernel -t ext4 -n --list | grep '\['
```

To show all mounts excluding submounts:

```
findmnt --kernel -n --list | grep -v '\['
```

To show all mounts of filesystems of type ext4 excluding submounts:

```
findmnt --kernel -t ext4 -n --list | grep -v '\['
```

The "-n" removes the headers and the "--list" removes the lines of the "tree" format.

Tested on Debian stretch.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset DONE1FSES
FSES=$(findmnt -vUPno SOURCE,FSROOT,TARGET,MAJ:MIN)
FSES=${FSES//MAJ:MIN/MAJ_MIN}
while read SEARCH1FS
do
  unset DONE2FSES
  eval "$SEARCH1FS"
  SEARCH1SOURCE=$SOURCE
  SEARCH1FSROOT=$FSROOT
  SEARCH1TARGET=$TARGET
  SEARCH1MAJMIN=$MAJ_MIN

  FS1WASHANDLED=0
  while read DONE1FS 
  do
    if [[ $DONE1FS == $MAJ_MIN ]]
    then
      FS1WASHANDLED=1
      break
    fi
  done < <(echo "$DONE1FSES")


  if [[ ($SEARCH1FSROOT == /) && ($FS1WASHANDLED == 0) ]]
  then
  DONE1FSES+=$MAJ_MIN$'\n'
  while read SEARCH2FS
  do
    eval "$SEARCH2FS"
    SEARCH2SOURCE=$SOURCE
    SEARCH2FSROOT=$FSROOT
    SEARCH2TARGET=$TARGET
    SEARCH2MAJMIN=$MAJ_MIN

    FS2WASHANDLED=0
    while read DONE2FS 
    do
      if [[ $DONE2FS == $SEARCH2FS ]]
      then
        FS2WASHANDLED=1
        break
      fi
    done < <(echo "$DONE2FSES")

    if [[ ($SEARCH1MAJMIN == $SEARCH2MAJMIN)  && ($SEARCH1TARGET != $SEARCH2TARGET )  && ($FS2WASHANDLED == 0 ) ]]
    then
      DONE2FSES+=$SEARCH2FS$'\n'
      echo "$SEARCH1TARGET$SEARCH2FSROOT   --> $SEARCH2TARGET"
    fi

  done < <(echo "$FSES")


  fi
done   < <(echo "$FSES")
```