# CentOS 7 - Can't mount /var/tmp as bind

Tags: centos, fstab, bind-mount

I'm working on a freshly installed CentOS7 with LVM. I want to bind mount /var/tmp to /tmp and added the following to /etc/fstab.

```
/tmp     /var/tmp     none     rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,bind     0 0
```

After a reboot, the /var/tmp is now mounted but not with bind option.
I've also tried following entry in /etc/fstab

```
/tmp     /var/tmp     none     bind     0 0
```

If I look at /etc/mtab. I can see my new mountpoint but no bind is displayed.

```
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system-var /var ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system-tmp /tmp ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system-home /home ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/mapper/system-tmp /var/tmp ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Can anybody help me out with the correct /etc/fstab entry?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the first occurrence was not made with bind.

Comment: this strange because this is the example solution provided by oscap ssg-rhel7-guide-C2S: see [link](http://static.open-scap.org/ssg-guides/ssg-rhel7-guide-C2S.html#xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_group_permissions) : "Bind Mount /var/tmp To /tmp". But anyway, how I can bind /var/tmp to /tmp? I don't see any bind in /etc/mtab

Comment: mtab is showing clearly that /var and /var/tmp is mounted on the same physical partition... There is notably already one bind mount working. I am afraid I am not following you.

Comment: yes that is true. And normaly I would say "ok, looks good" but there is a SCAP check which is searching for the keyword "bind" inside mtab. This is the check: `<ns6:pattern operation="pattern match">^[\s]*/tmp[\s]+/var/tmp[\s]+.*bind.*$</ns6:pattern>`. And we need to be SCAP compliant

Comment: wrong kernel? wrong version? who knows? My Debian Jessie  does not put the bind keywork inside mtab too.

Comment: Related: [*List only bind mounts*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18067/239817)